# Razor link to read file path from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm quite new to the concept of razor. Basically, I need to download .pdf files. The paths are stored in my database.

I need to have a hyperlink on my cshtml which will call a function inside my Controller.
Then, on my controller, it will fetch the path of my file, which will return to my cshtml and do a windows.open(path).

Please let me know how can this be possible or perhaps a better approach to perform what I need to do.

Thanks.

Example:

**.cshtml**

```
@Html.ActionLink (
linkText: "My Link",
actionName: "DownloadFiles",
controllerName: "Files",
routeValues: new 
{
   fileId: id,
   fileType: "PDF"
},
htmlAttributes: null

windows.open(path);
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult DownloadFiles(int fileId, string fileType) 
{
   string FilePath = "";
   FilePath = service.GetFilePath(fileId,fileType);

   return FilePath;
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mvc+download+file+from+server&oq=MVC+download&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l4.3503j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks, that leads to a solution too.

Comment: No problem. Just out of interest, didn't you think to google it first before asking the question?

Comment: Actually, I did search for several hours already and found no luck. Perhaps, since I'm lacking ideas about razor, I couldn't find the right keyword to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return fileresult which is a child class for ActionResult:

```
public FileResult DownloadFile()
{
   string FilePath = "";
   FilePath = service.GetFilePath(fileId,fileType);

   // add virtual file path only
   return File(FilePath, "application/pdf");
}
```

Here virtual path can be "~/Uploadfile/mypdf.pdf"